# How to correctly specify input shape for a Keras LSTM model

Tags: python, keras, generator, lstm

I have a generator that yields my x and y which is what I'm using to train my LSMT model in Keras.

The X is of the format [0.0, 1.0, 0.0004].

I set the shape of this data earlier:

```
x_out = np.array(list(x_drop.values())).reshape(len(x_drop), 1)
y_out = np.array([y])
```

Which I get in an async generator, so then I pass into a syncing function and then use model.fit_generator():

```
train_gen = to_sync_generator(replay(traintime_0, traintime_1, test=0))
    model = lstm_model()

model.fit_generator(
    train_gen,
    epochs = 5,
    verbose = 1,
    steps_per_epoch=500,
    initial_epoch=0,
    validation_data=valid_gen,
    validation_steps=500)
```

My model code is below.

```
   def lstm_model():
       model = Sequential()
       model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(3,1)))
       model.add(Dense(1))
       model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
       return model
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 1)
```

Note, I can not preprocess this data.

I haven't really seen examples of using lstm with non-preprocessed data, any advise is greatly appreciated! thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code relating to your data pipeline?

Comment: Sure, will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your data must be a tuple using the format (x, y, z), where => x is your batch number (you can initially start this with 1), y is your data array and z is your data shape.
By your case, I can deduce your data have one feature and has 3 steps. So, you can prepare it using the following code:

```
data = data.reshape((1, 3, 1))
```

If you cannot change the data directly, you can merge it into a new array, then fit the array into the model

Comment: Apologies, I guess my code wasn't clear, my train_gen returns an X,Y tuple of the form: ([0.0, 1.0, 0.0004], 0.25). so there's 3 features, 1 step. That means I should reshape to (1, 1, 3)?

Comment: But keep in mind it wont work properly, because you only have one cell/timestep (in LSTM, every timestep works as a cell, this is what you want to take advantage for in first place)

Comment: Why wouldn't it work properly? My lookback window is 100 periods, but I'm just feeding batches of 1 at a time. They shouldn't be related?

Comment: you're not getting the full potential of LSTM, in fact, the way you're using it (one time step per batch) makes your RNN works like an ANN (LSTM get benefits from the connection between timesteps). You can read more about it here: https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Comment: you use the timesteps to show how information evolves each time, you need at least two information cells (two timesteps) to take advantage of it

Comment: Right, but I thought they were unrelated. I thought batch_size was purely a procedural memory flow attribute, whereas the lookback period in my LSTM is what actually makes the connection between timesteps. If you take a look at this link: http://aaaquants.com/2017/08/27/machine-learning-lstm-networks/, it shows that the lookback is what defines the timesteps.